# MySQL pagination with limit returns the same values

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to do pagination, but the SQL query returns the same values on different pages. I show them the queries and the results, and it shows that there are ids that are repeated in both results.

I think it's the MySQL version because it works perfectly for me locally, I have the '10.4.22-MariaDB' version. Any help, solution, or suggestion, I can't change the server version.

Thanks so much.

[image: MySQL Version]

[image: Query 1]

[image: Query 2]

[image: Number of results]

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset

Comment: Does the expression used for ORDER BY is unique? if not then the rows returned in both SELECTs have the same value simply. And this is a norma! For the pagination you **must** use ORDER BY expression which provides the rows uniqueness. For example, use `ORDER BY fecha, id`.

Comment: In addition to @Akina suggestion, is it possible that table was changed externally between queries and some rows were added?

Comment: @SveKamenska No, it's static content that only I change, but I like the idea of using order by id

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Akina, it's not exactly the solution I was looking for, but it works perfectly.
My final query is the following, and the values are no longer shown repeated.

```
SELECT id FROM `obras` WHERE `estado` = 'publicado' AND `id_idioma` = 1 AND YEAR(fecha) >= '1980' ORDER BY `fecha` DESC, `id` DESC LIMIT 24;
```